Change the correct link for the $\LaTeX$ reference in our help center as well
According to this answer on the feature request "The MathJax help link should point to a more specific guide" we can change the link for our $\LaTeX$ help >>> here <<< to a site specific one. This is the feature request that follows the answer on that feature request.
To be precise, we would like that link to point to Using MathJax / $\TeX$ on the Cryptography site.
Thank you so much for adding the link to our formatting help available through the question mark of the formatting toolbar. This is however not available for answers (why?) and it doesn't change the link in the advanced help to the same location. For maximum reachability of the site specific help and symmetry we would like them to point to the same location.

This is done: 


Thank you again, Shog9.
